# c# Button font.height can't be set to Double Values. Can't convert from double to float

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button named button1. Using toolbox i can set the button font height to a double value, using properties then font,then size and i can set to 30.251. but when i set it programmatically, i cant write 30.251.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        double value=90.753/3;//the numerator & denominator came from certain computations

        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Font = new Font("Arial", value, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
 }
}
```

What is the problem?I need an exact value of font height up to 3decimal places. It show an error "Can't convert from double to float".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font size is float type not double
Try:

```
button1.Font = new Font("Arial", 30.251f, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Or if the value is in a double property use:

```
button1.Font = new Font("Arial", (float)fontSize, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Or if you want to get the number earlyer

```
float value=(float)(90.753/3);//the numerator & denominator came from certain computations
```

Or more clean

```
float value=90.753f/3;//the numerator & denominator came from certain computations
```

Comment: i forgot something. 30.251 is coming from a certain computation. value=some computation/some computation. see my edit